# Pattern Recognition in comparison

Tags: pattern-matching

I am totally new to pattern matching or recognition. My question is that, if I have a series of strings, say, str1: ABCAAAAAAAEFG, str2: ABCBBBBBBBBCC, str3: SSSCCCCCCCCEFG, etc.
I want to compare the strings and find out the shared patters in same positions.

For example, I want to compare str1 with str2, the result of the matching is that there is shared pattern: ABC from the beginning. The second step is to compare str1 with str3, the result is that there is a shred pattern: EFG from the end. I want to make this comparison for every two pairs in my set: (str1,str2), (str1,str3), (str2, str3). etc.

How can I do this programmatically. My question may be too general, but I am totally new to this area and I need to know if there are already some tools or functions out there that can help me to do this efficiently.

EDIT: 1) Normally, the strings have the same length.

Comment: What programming language would you like to use?

Comment: Preferably, java. But if you have solutions with other languages such as Python or C++ I can deal with them but may need some more effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be that difficult to write your own program to do this.

Start at 0 for both strings, compare.  If != move to next index, else mark that it was a match and move to next char.  Keep going till they don't match and note the matching substring. You can skip ahead to the next index in the string because you know that if you had matched from 0-n, that starting at 1 would still break at n and be of a smaller length.

Oh, and I hope you don't have too many strings, because you're going to need to do [n(n+1)/2 comparisons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) if you want to match every pair.

Comment: Yes I have too many strings and the strings are above 200 characters.

Comment: The strings being above 200 characters isn't a big deal (well, unless they're 20,000,000,000 characters).  The problem is you're going to have to do O(n^2) operations based on how many strings you have.  So the real question is, how many strings are "Too many strings"?  If N is really large, it's not going to matter how fast your matching is.